# How do i resolve the Keptn CLI Authentication Error?

Tags: authentication

When i try to authenticate the Keptn CLI with the Keptn Installation i get the following error:

```
$ ./keptn auth --endpoint=http://127.0.0.1.nip.io/api --api-token=LwUgcAN4cQFEGeb1nAw6vwgT0ibhD4qIEu38jsmn22Say
```

Starting to authenticate
Error: Authentication was unsuccessful. Post "http://127.0.0.1.nip.io/api/v1/auth": EOF

The Token and URL is correct.
I'm working inside of a Kind Cluster.

Has anybody had the same error and knows how to fix it?

Comment: Please post the error as text, not image

Comment: Sure, no problem

Comment: Which method did you use to access Keptn (ie, LoadBalancer, Ingress, NodePort, Port Forward)?